# Physical significance of knot vector in B-spline.

Tags: terminology, intuition, spline, curves

A B-spline blending curve formulation is:

> $P(u)=\sum_{k=0}^np_k B_{k,d}(u)$
>
> Given $n+1$ control points, B-spline blending functions are polynomials
>   of degree $d-1$, $(1<d<=n+1)$.

This much is easy to comprehend.

Now comes the part I am not able to make any sense of.

> Each polynomial function is defined over $d$ subintervals of the total
>   range of $u$. The selected set of subinterval endpoints $u_j$ is referred
>   to as a **knot vector**.

What is the purpose of **knot vector**? What is its physical significance?

Comment: I don't know what the physical allusion is, but a knot here is just a point of discontinuity (a point at which the function is not analytic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The knots are the argument values where the polynomial pieces join together. Or, saying it another way, between any two consecutive knot values, the spline is just a polynomial. So, the knot vector reflects the choices you made about how to build your spline from polynomial pieces.

To understand how knot values affect the shape of curves, geometrically, I recommend you read about "blossoming" (also known as "polar forms"). There's a good introduction [here](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch6.pdf). It's actually the knot *intervals* (distances between knot values) that affect the shape of the curve, not the knot values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to draw line segments between the knots (i.e. endpoints `u_j`) in the knot vector you'd get a jagged line.  The spline is a smooth path that goes through the same set of knots.

Comment: Since I already have a set of control points, and the curve is generated using the parameter `u`, what purpose do knot vectors serve? Why the need to further subdivide the intervals?